# i want ot create a customize bar in flex

Tags: apache-flex

there is a bar like in the following website which i am unable to create the one with blue in color and has a question mark can someone help me with that.

the Link : customize [bar](http://www.rprustagi.com/netzoom/netzoomdcmain.html)

thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you were more specific about what you're stuck on -- tell us what you've tried already and precisely where you're having trouble.

Comment: Although i have been answered by but still i could not make out as how to do this as i am new in this and been trying to create it on my own as for the practice as this technology is new to me.Thank you for the concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<mx:Canvas width="400" height="30" backgroundColor="#CDEFFF" borderStyle="solid" borderColor="#000000">
    <mx:Label text="Bar Title" verticalCenter="0" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="12" left="5"/>
    <mx:Image right="5" verticalCenter="1" source="question.png"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: @nitin: It would be the easiest to express your thanks by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. ;-)